# How can I read a custom event by a specific parameter sent from the frontend in Google Analytics 4 Data API?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-data-api

so we have a News application, the web/mobile developers log a custom event; for example:

```
firebase.analytics().logEvent('article_details', {
  id: 1234566,
});
```

this event is being sent whenever a user enters the article details screen.

On the backend, I am trying to retrieve the number of views per article. I am using [this GA4 Query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/) to create queries and test them. Here's

[image: my query]

I am using this from my NodeJs server

```
https://content-analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID}:runReport?alt=json
```

I was able to retrieve the event counts for this custom event, but I couldn't get the count by a specific article id; here's the

[image: response]

I am getting.

Ideally, I want to make an API call for a specific article to get its number of views(event counts)

how can I adjust my query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options how to return your results.

**1. Find it in Google Analytics 4 / Firebase interface**

Firstly, you need to register your parameter `id` in custom definitions. Basically GA4 / Firebase interface works with few parameters by default. At the moment you are sending custom event with custom parameter, which GA4 / Firebase doesn't know. It is needed to tell GA4 "Hey this is my new parameter, use it in interface".

You can find it here, how to register this parameter: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en (part: Create custom dimensions)

**2. Setup BigQuery export from your Google Analytics 4 / Firebase property**
You can set up a BigQuery export. The property will automatically export data to BigQuery in raw format. Over there you can run a SQL query to find results.

It is not needed to register parameter within GA4 / Firebase to query it in BigQuery.